# Language in a Sandbox in Rails

Tags: ruby, sandbox

I've found that there WAS a sandbox gem (created by the guys that made [try ruby in your browser](http://tryruby.hobix.com/) but it was compatible only with Ruby 1.8. Another problem is that I cannot find it anymore (it seems they stop serving the gem from the servers...).

So, is there any **secure** way of running ruby in a sandbox (so you can run it from your browser)?
Or an easy way to run (for example lua/python) in a sandbox (no filesystem access, no creation of objects etc) and be called from Ruby (Rails 2.2)?

I want to make an application like try_ruby even without having a ruby underneath. But it has to be an easy language (I saw there was a prolog in ruby, even a lisp but I don't think they are easy to learn languages...).

So, do you have any suggestions or tips? Or should I just start creating my own DSL in Ruby (if there is a solution in creating a somewhat safe system)?

Thx

Answer (score 4):

I am developing an implementation of a sandbox for ruby based on a modification of the ruby interpreter written in C, I have released recently a functional version of the gem called [shikashi](https://github.com/tario/shikashi/blob/master/README) ([rdoc documentation](http://tario.github.com/shikashi/doc/)).

Comment: hi i am trying to use your gem in rails project. i am getting this weird undefined method 'shadow' on enumerable.this is when access association proxy methods

Comment: Please, report the bugs to the main project page (https://github.com/tario/shikashi) ir order to be fixed faster.

Comment: This bug is no longer exists, due to a refactor of code to replace the ugly approach of hook, rallhook gem by shikashi, a more stable solution (many other problems also dissappeared)

Comment: Note that Shikashi appears to require an explicit whitelist of all methods/constants the user may use or assign. It's super safe...but probably too safe for what most people want in a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should try embedding JRuby in the browser.

http://ruby-in-browser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/evalruby/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The guy who wrote the original gem disappeared, Keyser Söze style:
http://www.rubyinside.com/why-the-lucky-stiff-is-missing-2278.html

I've read that the JRuby gem is more current or maintained, but I've found it buggy so far.  Here are some setup instructions:
http://flouri.sh/2009/4/4/how-to-set-up-the-jruby-sandbox

Overall, it looks like Ruby is lacking a solid implementation of this right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Another way is like codepad.org does it (VM isolation and checking the calls)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to run any language in a sandbox. But I found that JavaScript has been running as a sandbox language for a long time. [The ruby racer project](http://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) lets you embed the v8 engine in ruby. Hope that helps.