# A scripting engine for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, security, scripting, extensibility, sandbox

I am creating a Ruby On Rails website, and for one part it needs to be dynamic so that (sorta) trusted users can make parts of the website work differently. For this, I need a scripting language. In a sort of similar project in ASP.Net, I wrote my own scripting language/DSL. I can not use that source code(written at work) though, and I don't want to make another scripting language if I don't have to.

So, what choices do I have? The scripting must be locked down and not be able to crash my server or anything. I'd really like if I could use Ruby as the scripting language, but it's not strictly necessary. Also, this scripting part will be called on almost every request for the website, sometimes more than once. So, speed is a factor.

I looked at the RubyLuaBridge but it is Alpha status and seems dead.

**What choices for a scripting language do I have in a Ruby project?**

Also, I will have full control over where this project is deployed(root access), so there are no real limits..

Comment: What is the scripting engine supposed to be capable of exactly?

Comment: It just needs to be not too cryptic(suppose to be used by either beginner or non-programmers) and it needs to be Turing complete. It must be capable of interfacing with my Ruby program in order to get data to perform certain calculations and determinations. Also, it must be linkable with a commercial project, so no GPL but I'd like it to be open source.

Comment: You could always use `eval`, depending on how much you trust your users :)

Comment: @DR (btw, 2 letter names don't get notifications) I don't trust them that much is the problem. Even if I did, I still wouldn't trust a beginner programmer with an eval prompt on a live server.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406833/language-in-a-sandbox-in-rails

Comment: Would client-side Javascript be an option?  It would avoid one class of problems (doing dangerous things on your server) but open up another class (cross-site scripting attacks, naturally).  Depending on the use case, this might be an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: Well, maybe, I'd also have to be able to run the javascript on my server too because part of it is validation checks. I wouldn't want for people without javascript to get to do anything they want. and @Jesse, similar question, but also not any good answers. and hackety.org hasn't existed for a while now.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Why, why? WHY?

Comment: I'm sure there have been worse ideas, but I can't think of any right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [Rufus-lua](http://jmettraux.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/ruby-to-lua/) though it's at version 0.1.0...

Comment: rufus-lua is at 1.1.0 : http://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-lua 

it's used in other projects : http://github.com/scottpersinger/laminate

Comment: ooooh... laminate. I guess that proves that it can also be sandboxed within ruby. This will probably be the accepted answer..

Answer (score 1):

What about JRuby? You can use java implementation of many scripting language, such as javascript, scheme etc

Comment: If I was going to go that route, I'd probably just have a C-lua implementation and use IPC to communicate with it from my ruby program..

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it hasn't been suggested yet, there's [Locking Ruby In The Safe](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html) as described by the Pickaxe book. This allows you to use Ruby as the language without significant slowdown AFAIK.

This technique is *intended* to allow safe sandboxing of untrusted Ruby code and bug fixes and discussions are directed toward keeping it that way, but infinite loops and some other things still allow malicious users to peg the CPU. ([e.g. this discussion maybe](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/5966).)

What I don't know is how you return data that is inherently safe to use from outside the safe thread. A singleton object (for instance) can mimic whatever class and then do something dangerous when any method is called in the returning thread. I'm still googling around about it. (The Ruby Programming Language says that level 4 "Prevents metaprogramming methods" which would allow you to safely verify the class of a returned object, which I suppose would make results safe to use.)

Barring that, it might not be hard (*snrk*) to implement a Lisp-1 with dynamic scope since you already have a garbage collector.

Comment: lisp... sigh.. first problem: I don't know lisp, so I'd have to learn it and then implement it. Second problem: Lisp is not the most ideal beginner language..