# therubyrhino or therubyracer but for Ruby, not JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

Is there something like [therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino) or [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) but for JRuby, not JavaScript?

I tested `eval` but this allows to access all models and classes from my Rails-Project. I really want to force the code into an own environment (with only the standard classes) and want to extend this environment with some chosen variables and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's some good stuff for you here, I think.

[Language in a Sandbox in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406833/language-in-a-sandbox-in-rails)

and in general:

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ruby+sandbox