# Execute ruby code within limited environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

I am implementing a plugin architecture to a Rails project. The plugin architecture includes the ability for plugin writers to write Ruby code to be executed on the server. I want to make this secure so that plugin writers don't have the ability to write destructive code.

I think what I need to do, although I'm open to other options, is execute the Ruby code for the plugin in an isolated environment which has a limited scope. I'm thinking of something in the spirit of the [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gem but I want to safely execute Ruby instead of JavaScript.

I can't figure out a good way to do this. I thought of using `eval` with a limited `bindings` object, but I think it would be difficult to `eval` several files and I don't think I can adequately limit the bindings. For example, I don't want a plugin to be able to do something like a `destroy_all` on a model, or monkey-patch existing code in the app.

I'm quite stumped with this one. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You might have some luck with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406833/language-in-a-sandbox-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the following documentation about ruby safe levels. Sometimes services use the level 4 for scripts embedded by unknown users:

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html